# Why c# can make program with GUI on android and iOS but c++ cannot?

Tags: c#, android, c++, ios, user-interface

Mono touch can make C# compile on iOS and android

But why there is no C++ something can make C++ have native support of iOS and android.

I personally thought C++ could be more easier can C#.

Can anyone tell me why C# have cross-platform Gui but C++ don't have.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but C++ is vastly more complex than C#.

Comment: The Qt Framework (http://qt.nokia.com/) can do Android with Necessitas (http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/). It is still alpha-quality, but it is certainly possible to do in C++.

Comment: C++ is only platform independent if you use the standard library. For things like graphical user interfaces there is no built-in library. C# has a very extensive library, which is the same on all platforms and it includes the GUI parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, on Android you *can* [develop applications completely in C++](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html). You don't have direct access to all of the Java APIs, so you might still need a little bit of Java code in some cases. But you've got direct access to OpenGL ES, OpenSL ES, zlib, etc.

As for iOS.. well, they decided to go with Objective-C. It's worked out ok so far, but I understand that there's a slight learning curve if you come from a pure C/C++ background. At least the fact that iOS products are so popular these days means that finding information and learning material for ObjC isn't any problem.

Answer (score 0):

C# has a standardized GUI toolkit (.Net) and C++ does not have one. It is something C++ will not solve in the foreseeable future because it goes against some of c++ tenets, which calls for performance and generality when it comes to the standard library.

So, since GUIs are not standardized, it's improbable the C++ committee will go after such a thing that can make C++ very odd on some platforms.

On the other hand, independent frameworks, like Qt, could do it, but they have not showed such a interest, mainly because Qt cannot be used with commercial license on iOS because of contract restrictions upon Digia's business model when it comes to Apple.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#'s UI toolkit.  Mono has bindings for Android and iOS UI toolkits not writing some C# UI on Android or iOS.

Comment: It's what I am saying when I put .Net there. Mono acts like .Net on Windows. Please read carefully.

Comment: No.  Mono on Android does not act like .NET on windows.  It has bindings to Native Android OS.  Same with iOS.

Comment: And .Net has binds on native Windows. It is an implicit idea.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the Digia restrictions? The main problem AFAIK was that Nokia wasn't interested in keeping up the Qt crossplatform fame (for obvious reasons). Digia actually committed to make Qt a viable framework for iOS, Android and Windows Phone projects.